# Identifying overlap medication use

Tags: sas

Asked on SAS communitiesas well , havent gotten a correct response. 
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Identifying-overlap-medication-use/m-p/628115#M185541

I have a problem similar to the problem in -

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Concomitant-drug-medication-use/m-p/339879#M77587

However I have an issue , I have overlapping of same drug as well -

Eg:

```
+----+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | DRUG | START_DT  | DAYS_SUPP |  END_DT   |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | A    | 2/17/2010 |        30 | 3/19/2010 |
|  1 | A    | 3/17/2010 |        30 | 4/16/2010 |
|  1 | A    | 4/12/2010 |        30 | 5/12/2010 |
|  1 | A    | 8/20/2010 |        30 | 9/19/2010 |
|  1 | B    | 5/6/2009  |        30 | 6/5/2009  |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Here the three A prescriptions are over lapping .

So using the code in the link gives me combinations like A-A-B

whereas I don't want that.

However I want to account for the overlapping days for drug A. So I want to shift the second row prescription to 3/20/2010 to 4/19/2010. Similarly for 3rd A prescription.

the code I have tried -

```
data have2;
set have_sorted1;
format NEW_START_DT NEW_END_DT _lagEND_DT date9.;

_lagID = lag(patient_ID);
_lagDRUG = lag(drg_cls);
_lagEND_DT = lag(rx_ed_dt);

if patient_ID = _lagID and drg_cls= _lagDRUG and rx_st_dt <= _lagEND_DT then flag=1;
else flag = 0;


retain NEW_START_DT NEW_END_DT;

if flag=0 then do;
NEW_START_DT = rx_st_dt;
NEW_END_DT = rx_ed_dt;
end;
else do;
New_start_dt = NEW_End_DT + 1;
NEW_END_DT = new_start_dt + DAY_SUPP ;
end;
/* drop flag _:;*/
run;
```

But even then I get incorrect result -

```
id  Drug    drug_start  day_supp    drug_end    New_start   New_end
15  A   6-Sep-15    30  5-Oct-15    6-Sep-15    5-Oct-15
15  A   24-Sep-15   90  22-Dec-15   6-Oct-15    4-Jan-16
15  A   6-Dec-15    90  4-Mar-16    5-Jan-16    4-Apr-16
15  A   26-Feb-16   90  25-May-16   5-Apr-16    4-Jul-16
15  A   29-May-16   90  26-Aug-16   29-May-16   26-Aug-16
15  A   7-Dec-16    90  6-Mar-17    7-Dec-16    6-Mar-17
15  A   17-Feb-17   90  17-May-17   7-Mar-17    5-Jun-17
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phrjj.png]

Comment: Do other drugs ever appear interleaved while there is an overlap ? A A A B A where 3rd A overlaps 4th A ?  If so, do you want the shift to still occur ?  If no drug interleaving, is the sort order always based on `id, drug` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to track the 'flag' state implicitly in a shift variable that tracks how many days to shift forward.

Example:

Shift is always applied, but will be zero when no overlap occurs.  The prior end, after computation, is tracked in a retained variable.  The code does not need to rely on `LAG`.

```
data have;
infile cards firstobs=3 dlm='|';
input ID DRUG: $ START_DT: mmddyy10. DAYS_SUPP END_DT: mmddyy10.;
format start_dt end_dt mmddyy10.;
datalines;
| ID | DRUG | START_DT  | DAYS_SUPP |  END_DT   |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | A    | 2/17/2010 |        30 | 3/19/2010 |
|  1 | A    | 3/17/2010 |        30 | 4/16/2010 |
|  1 | A    | 4/12/2010 |        30 | 5/12/2010 |
|  1 | A    | 8/20/2010 |        30 | 9/19/2010 |
|  1 | B    | 5/6/2009  |        30 | 6/5/2009  |
;

data want;
  set have;
  by id drug;

  retain shift prior_shifted_end;

  select;
    when (first.drug) shift = 0;
    when (prior_shifted_end > start_dt) shift = prior_shifted_end - start_dt + 1;
    otherwise shift = 0;
  end;

  original_start_dt = start_dt;
  original_end_dt = end_dt;

  start_dt + shift;
  end_dt + shift;

  prior_shifted_end = end_dt;

  format prior: original: mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This approach of not depending on lag is great.